# Navigate from one Detail View contorller to another Detail VC in Splitview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have multiple DetialViewController for my Split View. I have a scenario where I need to navigate from one `DetailViewController`  to another. Both are in the Splitview in an iPad. When I try to push or modal the destination view, the whole view appears but not as a split view with menu or Master View Controller on the left.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to take a look at [THIS EXAMPLE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Listings/Classes_DetailViewManager_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775-Classes_DetailViewManager_m-DontLinkElementID_6) by Apple itself where there are multiple DetailViewContrllers are handles beautifully

here you will find DetailView manager which manages which detail view controller should be shown as per user inputs.I guess this what you want.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To manages which **detailViewController** should be shown. I'll post a sample code and explain the idea, so hope you will find your solution by stand against this idea.Suppose I had a **splitView** which added to right of **mainView**: when user click on an item which shown into the **splitView** -> action is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MenuItem *item = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(item && [item controller]) {
        UINavigationController *currentNav= [splitView.viewControllers lastObject];
        UIViewController *currentVC = currentNav.viewControllers[0];
        if(currentVC != [item controller]) {
            UINavigationController *newNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[item controller]];
            NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController,newNavigation,nil];
            splitView.viewControllers = newVCs;
            splitView.delegate = [item controller];
        }
    }
}
```

The class **MenuItem** manages the items which had add into **splitView**. And **menuItems** is an array which include the items into **splitView**. And then when user click on an item I will check the new controller with the current by the statement:`if(currentVC != [item controller])`. into **MenuItem** will have a variable **UIViewController *controller** and just do a method:

```
 - (MenuItem*)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title controller:(UIViewController *)_controller imageName:(NSString *)_imageName {
    self.title = _title;
    self.controller = _controller;
    self.imageName = _imageName;
    return self;
}
```

This method will call when you need add controller as bellow method:

```
    - (void) initMenuItems
{
    menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Item1 *itm1 =[[Item1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"item1" bundle:nil];   
    Item2 *itm2 = [[Item2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"item2" bundle:nil];
    Item3 *itm3 = [[Item3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"item3" bundle:nil];
    [menuItems addObject:itm1];
    [menuItems addObject:itm2];
    [menuItems addObject:itm3];
}
```

call this method into **viewDidLoad** of your **mainViewController**

Hope this will help